# While using Microsoft edge in windows 10, I get a switch app pop up? Anyone can suggest how to block it?

Tags: microsoft-edge

When a user clicks a button on a website, .ex file is launched. But browser gives a pop up to switch app before launching exe. Can any suggest how to remove the pop up?

Comment: Can you provide some more details like a screenshot of the pop up?

Comment: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-other_settings/microsoft-edge-how-to-disable-did-you-mean-to/8f6ac309-713c-4669-8469-d878dfa983fb

Comment: Please open the url above, the same pop appears when i try to open any 3rd party exe file from Microsoft edge.